# Precision-Recall Curve Intuition for Multi-Class Classification Utilizing SoftMax Activation

Tags: python, classification, multiclass-classification, softmax

I am running a CNN image multi-class classification model with Keras/Tensorflow and have established about a 90% overall accuracy with my best model trial. I have 10 unique classes I am trying to classify. However I want to present a PRC for the individual classes. I am trying to wrap my head around the intuition behind using thresholds for each class.

Since I utilize a `SoftMax` output layer activation I end up with a probability distribution for the 10 class label possibilities. If I am to create a `PRC` for this, I utilize different thresholds for each individual class and then classify the image as positive or negative depending on the probability.

Now in reality suppose I was using a threshold of `0.4` and my `softmax` activation gave me `P(dog) = .41` and `P(cat) = .42` and then small probabilities for the other classes. Thus with this threshold I am confirming my `dog` image as a `dog` even though the `softmax` probability was higher for `cat`.

Can someone explain to me how this makes sense in practice (if I were to deploy a classification model like this). My model would of course classify this image as a cat in practice since `softmax` chooses class with highest probability. What exactly is my `PRC` actually helping with when presenting evaluation metrics? Is it simply just showing how an individual class performs in the binary sense with a threshold for classification? In practice it wouldn't be using these thresholds for actual prediction.

Here is an example of what my PRC looks like for my validation set.

[image]

The code I used to produce it is utilizing one-vs-all methodology with `sklearn`

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from pathlib import Path
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
from typing import Tuple
from itertools import cycle

def assess_pr_curve(model, xtrain: np.ndarray, ytrain: np.ndarray, xval: np.ndarray, yval: np.ndarray, xtest: np.ndarray, ytest: np.ndarray, 
                    save_plot_path: Path, n_classes: int, class_labels: list):
    """
    Get Precision and Recall and P/R Curve plots for Validation and Test data
    """

    feature_extractor = Model(inputs = model.inputs, outputs = model.get_layer('dense').output) # extract dense output layer (will be softmax probabilities)

    y_train_score = feature_extractor.predict(xtrain, batch_size = 64) # softmax probabilities for training data
    y_train_binary = label_binarize(ytrain, classes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) # one hot encode train data

    y_val_score = feature_extractor.predict(xval, batch_size = 64) # softmax probability for validation data
    y_val_binary = label_binarize(yval, classes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) # one hot encode validation data

    y_test_score = feature_extractor.predict(xtest, batch_size = 64) # one hot encoded softmax predictions
    y_test_binary = label_binarize(ytest, classes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) # one hot encode the test data true labels

    # Precision-Recall Curves for train/val/test
    train_precision = dict()
    train_recall = dict()
    train_avg_precision = dict()

    val_precision = dict()
    val_recall = dict()
    val_avg_precision = dict()

    test_precision = dict()
    test_recall = dict()
    test_avg_precision = dict()

    for i in range(n_classes):
        train_precision[i], train_recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_train_binary[:, i], y_train_score[:, i])
        train_avg_precision[i] = average_precision_score(y_train_binary[:, i], y_train_score[:, i])
        val_precision[i], val_recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_val_binary[:, i], y_val_score[:, i])
        val_avg_precision[i] = average_precision_score(y_val_binary[:, i], y_val_score[:, i])
        test_precision[i], test_recall[i], _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test_binary[:, i], y_test_score[:, i])
        test_avg_precision[i] = average_precision_score(y_test_binary[:, i], y_test_score[:, i])

    colors = cycle(['blue', 'red', 'green', 'brown', 'purple', 'pink', 'orange', 'black', 'yellow', 'cyan'])

    # plot each class curve on single graph for multi-class one vs all classification
    for i, color, lbl in zip(range(n_classes), colors, class_labels):
        plt.plot(train_recall[i], train_precision[i], color = color, lw = 2,
        label = 'P/R Curve of class {0} (avg = {1:0.3f})'.format(lbl, train_avg_precision[i]))
    plt.hlines(0, xmin = -0.02, xmax = 1.0, linestyle = 'dashed')
    plt.xlim([-0.02, 1.03])
    plt.ylim([-0.03, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('Recall')
    plt.ylabel('Precision')
    plt.title('Train P/R Curve for CIFAR-10 Multi-Class Data')
    plt.legend(loc = 'center left', prop = {'size': 6})
    fullpath = save_plot_path.joinpath('train_pr_curve.png')
    plt.savefig(fullpath)
    plt.close()


    # plot each class curve on single graph for multi-class one vs all classification
    for i, color, lbl in zip(range(n_classes), colors, class_labels):
        plt.plot(val_recall[i], val_precision[i], color = color, lw = 2,
        label = 'P/R Curve of class {0} (avg = {1:0.3f})'.format(lbl, val_avg_precision[i]))
    plt.hlines(0, xmin = -0.02, xmax = 1.0, linestyle = 'dashed')
    plt.xlim([-0.02, 1.03])
    plt.ylim([-0.03, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('Recall')
    plt.ylabel('Precision')
    plt.title('Validation P/R Curve CIFAR-10 Multi-Class Data')
    plt.legend(loc = 'center left', prop = {'size': 6})
    fullpath = save_plot_path.joinpath('val_pr_curve.png')
    plt.savefig(fullpath)
    plt.close()

    # plot each class curve on single graph for multi-class one vs all classification
    for i, color, lbl in zip(range(n_classes), colors, class_labels):
        plt.plot(test_recall[i], test_precision[i], color = color, lw = 2,
        label = 'P/R Curve of class {0} (avg = {1:0.3f})'.format(lbl, test_avg_precision[i]))
    plt.hlines(0, xmin = -0.02, xmax = 1.0, linestyle = 'dashed')
    plt.xlim([-0.02, 1.03])
    plt.ylim([-0.03, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('Recall')
    plt.ylabel('Precision')
    plt.title('Test P/R Curve for CIFAR-10 Multi-Class Data')
    plt.legend(loc = 'center left', prop = {'size': 6})
    fullpath = save_plot_path.joinpath('test_pr_curve.png')
    plt.savefig(fullpath)
    plt.close()
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info on how you built those curve (code ?). I suspect that they are 'one versus all' AUC curve, i.e. reformulating a multiclass problem into multiple binary ones.

Comment: @Icrmorin Updated the post with the code.